# Can i fetch the parent name of an object in a custom email template

Tags: visual-workflow, email-template, process, builder

I have to fetch a lookup field of the object Opportunity.Instead of this Dear {!Opportunity.Primary_Contact__c} I need Dear {!Opportunity.Primary_Contact__r.Name}.But each time I input this and save the value it gets changed.When I searched I came to know that cross object is not possible.So the only way is to provide a formula field and use it in the grant fetching the first and last name of primary contact and concatenating it?

Comment: In the formula field you can fetch it by using Primary_Contact__r.Name, you will get firstname & lastname then refer that formula field in email template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Answer to the question yes using Cross Object merge fields do not work in case of email templates as per the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000324867&type=1) by salesforce. As workaround provided in the article is to create a hidden formula field and use that formula field in the template.

Please find the [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdifOUAR/cross-object-merge-fields-in-email-template) for the same in the Idea Exchange for the same where you can upvote for the same.